# Блатной угол - что это значит?

Tags: значения

> Гости остановились у нас в совершенно блатном углу в специальном кубрике для вип-гостей.

(В. Березин, *Путевые знаки*)

Что значит *блатной угол*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь "угол" в смысле "комната", "место" (для постоя). "Блатной" может также иметь разные значения, здесь - "особенно хорошее", "доступное только для особых персон".

Слово "блатной" имеет сниженную стилистику. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82

Comment: сниженный - это значит "vulgar"?

Comment: @marmistrz В данном случае это, скорее, жаргон (jargon), но жаргон широко распространенный.

Comment: Значит если в словаре при каким-нибудь слове увижу сокращение *сниж.*, то заглавное слово является жаргонным, не так ли?

Comment: @marmistrz Жаргон сокращается как "жарг.", сниженное - как "сниж". Ради интереса посмотрел, что на самом деле пишут словари по поводу "блат/блатной". Данное значение чаще всего трактуется как "прост." (т.е. просторечие); особую пометку "жарг." (жаргон) имеет только значение "блатной" = воровской, криминальный.

Comment: @marmistrz Т.е. в данном случае словари трактуют слово "блатной" именно как "vulgar" (просторечие), хотя где-то попалась и пометка "разг." (разговорное) - не уверен, какому иностранному термину может соответствовать последнее.

Comment: Разговорное - это вероятно *colloquial*. Что-то в таком случае значит вообще *сниженное* в словаре? `спутаться` тоже определяется *разговорно-сниженным*, но я не сказал бы, что это слово вульгарное (но могу ошибаться). Чем отличается слово сниженное от разговорного?

Comment: @marmistrz Слово "спутаться" в прямом смысле - это совершенно обычное слово (то же, что и "запутаться", "перепутаться" и т.п.). А вот в переносном смысле "спутаться" действительно стоит в словарях "с пометкой". При чём в одних "прост.", в других "сниж." Кроме того, учитывайте, что есть и слово "вульгарный"/"вульгаризм", так что вполне может встретиться соответствующая словарная метка - "вульг." Так что тут не мудрено и запутаться.